# External HDMI display not detected after boot

Tags: display, hdmi

I have a 4k laptop and 4k external display connected through HDMI.

If I connect the display, then boot up the system, it detects it just fine, and works. But when I connect it after boot, it doesn't get detected. The "Detect Displays" button in System Settings does nothing. **How to make it detect it?**

If the automatic detection after boot is currently buggy, **is there a command to redetect displays?** (Presumably the same way the system does on boot?)

- OS: `elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki x86_64`
- Kernel: `4.13.10-041310-generic`

I also have the `elementary-os/daily` PPA installed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why or when, but it sorted itself - probably one of the `daily` patches. Thanks, eOS team!